# Who can guess this five letter word the fastest?

Tags: riddle, word

Pride comes before fall, but I come before these words. Can you solve each of these clues to reveal me?

A five letter word will precede the word(s) in the following clues:

> 1. A race title. (_ _ _ _)

> 2. A popular vacation spot for those who like to explore.
>    (_ _ _ _ _ _)

> 3. Just add one letter and I become the third biggest refreshment in ounce-age for you hipsters.
>    (_)

> 4. A group of individuals who are pretty judgmental.
>    (_ _ _ _)

> 5. The classification of several big games annually, normally involving a racket.
>    (_ _ _ _)

> 6. A very bad sickness which causes muscle spasms and loss of consciousness.
>    (_ _ _)

> 7. A popular video game if you enjoy being a bad guy.
>    (_ _ _ _ _ / _ _ _ _)

> 8. This is a home of music for westerners and southerners alike.
>    (_ _ _ / _ _ _ _)

> 9. Need to get somewhere underground? Come hear and I'll also tell you what time it is.
>    (_ _ _ _ _ _ _ / _ _ _ _ _ _ _)

> 10. The opposite of downleft is an inferior type of what this is... it will still tickle your ears though.
>     (_ _ _ _ _)

Please also solve each clue!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Grand is the five-letter word you are looking for.

> 1. Prix

> 2. Cayman or Bahama or Canyon (@DEEM)

> 3. [Grand]e

> 4. Jury

> 5. Slam

> 6. Mal

> 7. Theft Auto

> 8. Ole Opry

> 9. Central Station

> 10. Piano

Comment: Haha, great job! You are correct, except for clue 2, almost! You are super quick though! @RobPratt

Comment: @Crozier Is the prize for a correct solution 1000 pounds/dollars/euros/whatever?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Lol, you wish! 1,000 upvotes would work even better xD.

Comment: Missed out on Tenaq Pnalba  Tenaq Zbeavre :)

Comment: @DEEM, second one is too long.

Comment: Actually @DEEM is correct with his first part :D